Movie with a guy in a perfect "virtual reality" world
Long time ago I've watched one considerably influential film. It was in English and it is older than 2001. However, I am unable to find it anymore in the list of Virtual Reality Movies from the "imdb" and everywhere else for that matter.

It was about one machine that was initially a prototype that simulates a virtual world inside your own mind. The end of the movie as far as I remember was how this machine becomes viral "Just like the TV nowadays".
At the beginning, the engineers of this machine donated one to the main character to test it out. Once he entered, he asked how come he can feel the taste of the grapes. However, he began to spend increasingly large amount of time in the machine, eating whatever he desires, meeting the woman of his dreams, attending beautiful places and as a result of this, suddenly his life was in danger... out of hunger, dehydration and weariness.
Additionally I want to interject that there was something like a programmed projection of a steward that receives the traveler's commands and desired changes in the environment. Also, the main character had to put specific gloves while being inside the machine.

What is the name of this movie, please.

@Richard Whatever this is, it doesn't seem identical.

If this is "inception". I actually have watched it yesterday. Pretty inspiring movie I can say. All the time.. attractive somehow. The one I am seeking for is definitely older.

Sounds familiar... Country\language and an approximate year would truly help us out.

English speech. Nothing more that I know of. And It is older than 2010

The main character also had to put specific gloves while being inside the machine.

The features you mentioned could be find in many of this kind movies. Try to remember and mention some special feature only coulde be found your movie.

A wild stab in the dark but is it Existenz? It doesn't quite fit with your description but its close enough for me to ask.

It sounds somewhat like Brainstorm with Christopher Walken.

It isn't existenZ

@klaymen Well that's just not true. The features are quite specific and at least I haven't seen a movie that goes even close to this (considering that I've checked a number of them already). Source: eyes.

I think it best corresponds to the film:
Virtual Seduction "Cybersex" 1995


Although, I am not able to find it for watch. So I can not confirm with frantic certitude.
Moreover, It greatly response to the description provided in this question.

After I successfully succeeded to obtain it and watch it,
I can confirm that this is the movie I was looking for.
It looks pretty well-made for its time, so the critics rating in IMDB are unfounded imo.. just like the description of the movie. It's horrible.
